# Possible to validate against elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, ecmascript-6

I am using [validate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate) to validate input, and I need to validate an input that has to be one of the numbers in my `arr`.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 14];

const p = {
  System: {
    type: Number,
    enum: arr,
    required: true
  }
};
```

If I try `enum: arr`, then it takes the entire array and not just one of the elements.

Question

Is it possible to get `validate` to use one of the numbers from `arr`?

Comment: enum checks if the input number is in the array.

Comment: Can you please share the rest of your code? Are you using `new Scheme(p)` anywhere? How are you calling `.validate()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Schema from 'validate'
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 14];

const p_schema = new Schema({
  System: {
    type: Number,
    enum: [...arr],
    required: true
  }
});
let p = {
    System: 9
}

const errors = p_schema.validate(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `enum` rule, the value of `System` must be one of the values in the array.
The problem with your code however is that you didn't call `Scheme` from the validate package, so here what you need to change:

```js
import Schema from "validate";

const arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 14];
const v = new Schema({
  System: {
    type: Number,
    enum: arr,
    required: true,
  },
});

// For testing
const error = v.validate({ System: 3 });
```